# Android - get manifest meta-data out of activity

Tags: java, android

I want to do something like this

```
private static final String url;
private static final String pass;
private static final String user;

static {
    Bundle metadata = ctx.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
    url = (String) metadata.get("JMSQueueURL");
    user = (String) metadata.get("JMSQueueUsername");
    pass = (String) metadata.get("JMSQueuePassword");
}
```

So far it was in activity (but not as static), so that I was possible to get package manager, but now i want to move this piece of code to another class which doesn't inherits ContextWrapper (from where we can get package manager). Is it possible somehow? This class is something like util class.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `Context` from the calling method to the method in the `Util` class and use the context there to get the details you want. This way you can call the method in the `Util` class from different modules in your application, with different contexts.

```
// Calling the Util method
Bundle metadata = Util.getMetaData(context);
...
// Inside the Util class
public static Bundle getMetaData(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but that's not what i want. I'd better like to inject context to this Util class.

Answer (score 0):

This allows me to access the metadata from anywhere in my application, without a context:

```java
public class MyAndroidApp extends Application {

    private static MyAndroidApp instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyAndroidApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Bundle getMetadata() {
        try {
            return getInstance()
                    .getPackageManager()
                    .getApplicationInfo(getInstance().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
                    .metaData;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```